# XML formatting regex merge lines and keep indentation

Tags: regex, xml

I've got xml files that I want to apply universal formatting to using regex.
Basically what I want is to have these 2 lines on 1 line.

```
      ]]>
    </query>
```

AND
have it with the same indentation as the opening tag.

So this example (or any variation to it)

```
  <search>
    <query><![CDATA[
      testline1
      ]]>
    </query>
  </search>
```

Should become this

```
  <search>
    <query><![CDATA[
      testline1
    ]]></query>
  </search>
```

[See my example here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rI6MSm/1)

Comment: You need to use `.*?` with a dotall modifier, `(\s*)(<query><!\[CDATA\[\n(.+?))\]\]>\n*<\/query>`. See https://regex101.com/r/rI6MSm/2

Comment: It's usually not recommended to use regex on xml - an xml parser is preferred. Depending on the language you use, the desired output can be obtained. For example, in python you could use the lxml library.

Comment: @Wiktor
The first example is what it should look like, the second is an example that needs formatting. But isn't selected. Do you have an idea for that?

Comment: @Jack
I'm developping dashboards in visual studio code. So it's just to format actual files, not dynamic code. But any solution will do, so if you know a good parser as an extension, making this format possible feel free to send the link :)

Comment: See answer below on how to do it with python. It's too long for a comment, and if it's not relevant to what you're doing, no big deal.

Comment: See `(<query><!\[CDATA\[\n[\w\W]*?)]]>\s*<\/query>`, see https://regex101.com/r/rI6MSm/3

Comment: Ok now it's selected but still the indentation is off. The closing should be on the same height as the opening.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with python:

```
from lxml import etree
test = """your xml above"""

doc = etree.XML(test)
target = doc.xpath('//query')[0]
target.text = etree.CDATA("".join(target.text.rsplit('\n',1)))
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<search>
    <query><![CDATA[
      testline1
          ]]></query>
  </search>
```